# Wrap each form in formset with a div including unmentioned fields with django crispy forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, formsets

I'm using the following code to wrap all the form fields of a form in a formset together in a div with django crispy forms:

```
class OperatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OperatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs):
            self.helper = FormHelper(self)
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.all().wrap_together(Div, css_class="operator-form")
            self.helper.render_unmentioned_fields = True

    class Meta:
        model = Operator
        fields = tuple(fields_list)
```

Instantiating FormHelper with 'self' autogenerates the layout without having to specify all fields. I need this because my fields are dynamically generated. The problem is that the DELETE and ORDER fields are not added to the layout. So I set render_unmentioned_fields to True. With this setting these two fields at least show up in the form, but are not wrapped with the rest of the fields in the div.

I know I can manually iterate over the forms in a formset and wrap them with a div, which is what I've been doing up to now, but this requires manual handling of the non form errors of the formset, which is usually done automatically by crispy.

**EDIT**: Updated code as requested. This entire class is actually wrapped in a factory method that populates fields_list, so that I can dynamically include only certain fields. ORDER and DELETE are left out on purpose. They are automatically detected (including them results in an error) and display in the form, they are simply not wrapped in the div.

Comment: Post all of the code in the form class definition, please.

Comment: Are you intentionally leaving out the DELETE and ORDER fields?

Comment: Updated as requested. @BrianDant

Comment: Move the `self.helper.render_unmentioned_fields = True` above the previous line, and see what that does.

Comment: Doesn't work. render_unmentioned_fields is simply a flag. By the time it is set, the layout has already been populated. The methods all() and wrap_together don't evaluate it at all. So I expect that this is a missing feature/bug in crispy forms and not something that can be easily worked around.

Comment: This might be a side point, that doesn't help:  I don't see the need to pass `self` to `FormHelper`.  In the [fundamentals section of the docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html#fundamentals), they are instantiating a `FormHelper` without passing `self`, and they get the entire layout.  

You should be hesitant to assume that Crispy is missing a feature, or this is a bug, as this is one of the problems it sets out to solve.

Have you looked into [updating layouts on the go](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/dynamic_layouts.html) in your view?

Comment: You don't get a layout object if you don't pass `self` to `FormHelper`. You will notice in the docs (your first link) that they build the layout manually when they instantiate without `self`. I will have to try out updating on the go, thanks for the suggestiong, but if you're not allowed to add DELETE and ORDER manually then I don't think doing it on the go will be any different. Unless of course you may add them when not instantiating with self. Either way, I would have thought that things that work without `self` should work with `self` as well.

Comment: The reason why my DELETE and ORDER fields are not wrapped can be traced to the render_layout method in helper.py of crispy forms. The layout is rendered completely (together with wraps and all) and only after that the unmentioned fields are rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian Dant suggested, ORDER and DELETE should be added manually if they are to be included in the `Layout`. My problem was that I also passed them to the `Meta` class's `fields'.

```
class _OperatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(_OperatorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout.extend(['ORDER', 'DELETE'])
        self.helper.all().wrap_together(Div, css_class="operator-form")

    class Meta:
        model = ApplicationOperator
        fields = tuple(fields_list)
```